# react-native installing react-native-gesture-handler just hands and doesn't install

Tags: reactjs, navigation

I am trying to install react-navigation so I can add navigation to my react app.  I am following the instructions on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation but I can not get it to all install properly.

I am on a windows machine and have react versions

- "react": "16.9.0",
- "react-native": "0.61.5",

I installed react-native

```
npm install -g react-native
```

I installed the cli

```
npm install -g --save react-native-cli
```

I created my app

```
react-native init MyReactNativeApp
```

I cd'ed into that folder

```
cd MyReactNativeApp
```

I installed react-navigation

```
npm install -g --save react-navigation
npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack
```

I am trying to run the next step which is the following, however it just hangs

```
If you have an bare React Native project, install the dependencies with npm:

npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Further investigations shows i can install all the following all ok

```
npm install react-native-reanimated 
npm install react-native-screens 
npm install react-native-safe-area-context 
npm install @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Its the install of "react-native-gesture-handler" which just hangs, i do not get any error message

```
npm --save install react-native-gesture-handler
[..................] - loadDep:prop-types: sill resolveWithNewModule react-native-gesture-handler@1.5.6 checking installable status
```

I have searched the net and tried a number of things, such as those below but nothing works

- run my command window as an administrator
- removed the react-native-safe-area-view folder from node-modules and tried again
- put my GIT home on my PATH

I believe without this i can not use react-navigation and my app fails to run.

I do not understand why this is not working when i am following the official documentation.

**UPDATE**

Eventually it failed (after about 10 mins) with

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t 
https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02- 
12T13_26_03_301Z-debug.log
```

The log file contents do not say anything more than the error

```
43 error Error while executing:
43 error C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t 
https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
43 error
43 error undefined
43 error exited with error code: 128
```

**GIT on my machine**

```
 >which git
 C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE

 >git --version
 git version 2.21.0.windows.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error implied that GIT can not access the given site. I'm behind a corporate Firewall. I set a proxy in git and I can now install "react-native-gesture-handler"

```
 git config --global http.proxy http://host:port
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm you have git installer and available in command line
2. Since you are using rn 61, you should initialize your project with npx

`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

Comment: 1) I have updated my post with my GIT environment 
2) Thank you for the note about using npx to create the apps when on react-native 61. Does this create a slightly different app than without it?

Comment: not sure how much it differs but this message is in the documentation "If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues" https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: Thank you Roberto. I saw that and tried that as well. However without the global react-native-cli i can not create projects as it fails that there is no template! I get the error
"error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-oVhz8S\node_modules\react-native\template.config'"